# Combining mapfile, command redirection and exit status retrieval

Tags: bash, io-redirection, exit-code

I am reading a build command as so:

```
mapfile -t make_out < <(2>&1 ./make.sh my_program)
```

I would like to print the output kept in `make_out` **only** if the build failed. How would I both keep the exit status, and save the output for later use (respecting spacing, newlines, and in general safe parsing)?

I am open to changing the way I read the results, but I do not want solutions saving stuff in an extra file or relying on analyzing the text. It is valid if this cannot be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable *lastpipe* option and turn the command into a pipeline; so that `mapfile` is run in the current execution environment, and `./make.sh`'s exit status can be retrieved from `PIPESTATUS` array.

```
# call set +m first if job control is enabled
shopt -s lastpipe
./make.sh my_program 2>&1 | mapfile -t make_out
if [[ PIPESTATUS[0] -ne 0 ]]; then
  printf '%s\n' "${make_out[@]}"
fi
# revert changes to shell options if necessary
```

Comment: For some reason `echo 3 | mapfile -t bla` results in an empty `bla`. I never saw piping into `mapfile` - do I need to do something to make it work.

Comment: Ahhh, it's running in a subshell (due to the pipe) and thus the array is not declared in the current shell. This solution  will not work.

Comment: @kabanus: `lastpipe` runs the last command in pipeline in the current shell - https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines is what I came up with lately. In short, supply the exit code as the last array element and carve it out:

```bash
mapfile -t make_out < <(2>&1 ./make.sh my_program; echo ${?})

declare -ir exit_code=${make_out[-1]}
unset make_out[-1]

if ((exit_code != 0))
then
        printf '%s\n' "${make_out[@]}"
fi
```